# Auctex support for building using makefile in subdirectory?

Tags: emacs, auctex, makefile

I am editing my PhD thesis using Emacs & Auctex, but my elisp is quite weak. Additionally, I build my thesis in a subdirectory, using makefiles generated by CMake and the UseLATEX CMake package, which I highly recommend.

I can’t figure out how to tell auctex that when I build the document it should do something like: `make -C build/digital` and that the pdf file being output is going to be at build/digital/thesis.pdf even though the source is at ./thesis.tex

p.s. I HIGHLY recommend checking out UseLATEX, the CMake package for easily compiling LaTeX documents.

Comment: I would just as highly recommend using Arara, another TeX automation tool. :) But this is not the question. The support can definitely be added to AUCTeX, though I don't have the environment right now to provide a solution.

Comment: `M-x compile RET` and then you can pass all arguments you want to `make`.

Comment: +1 for giordano's suggestion; I would even go further and say to create your own function and let-bind `compile-command` so you don't have to type it in each session: `(defun my:tex-compile () (interactive) (let ((compile-command "make -C build/digital")) (call-interactively #'compile)))`  But again, this isn't an answer to the question, just a solution to the problem :)

Comment: Yes, I have been doing M-x compile, but I’d like all the fancy keybindings of AUCTeX to work, especially the viewer and build commands, since I am using synclatex and skim to enable jumping from source-line to output-line (forward search) and vice-versa

Answer (score 7):

Add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex" '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("Make" "make" TeX-run-compile nil t)))
```

Then you'll be able to call the `make` program with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> `Make` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Replace the second element of the list with `"make -C build/digital"` if you want `"make -C build/digital"` by default, and the fourth element to `t` instead of `nil` if you want to have the chance to modify the `make` command instead of sticking with the default (which you can change interactively with <kbd>C-u C-c C-c</kbd> anyway).

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but AUCTeX still doesn’t know to look for the pdf in build/digital. Is there a way to tell it about this?

Comment: Currently AUCTeX doesn't support output files with a different name or path than the default one (same path and base name of the master file + proper extension).  I worked on it for some time in the past, but didn't complete the task.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue as the OP, and was thinking along the following lines: Could the `TeX-run-compile` command default to look for the Makefile in the same directory as the TeX-master? Then, assuming that the output file has the same base name as the TeX-master, the "view" command should work out of the box.

Comment: @Sweeters What you describe is what happens with AUCTeX 11.88.

Comment: @giordano That sounds like a very opportune update! I will give v11.88 a try ASAP, but I'm afraid I cannot find any relevant entry in the AUCTeX 11.88 manual (neither the "Processing" section nor the changelog). Could you please give me a pointer?

Comment: @Sweeters it's in the catch-all entry "There have been lots of bug fixes and feature additions." `;-)`  It has been fixed with [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=d3a5e9d12a161595c28f1c1498a1e12f5709b44b&ignorews=1) (please note Savannah servers are pretty slow today due to maintenance work).

Comment: One thing that I tried was to create a symlink to build/digital/thesis.pdf, however, AUCTeX didn't seem to like this, for some reason...

Comment: @giordano AUCTeX 11.88 and the elisp code in your answer work like a charm! Thanks

Comment: @giordano Thank you for your answer, it's been useful. Though I'm not sure if something changed since you gave it or if it's something in my settings, but I had to use it with a `(eval-after-load "tex" ...)` to get it working.

Comment: @gusbrs you're right, that's necessary.